# REST API call shows 404 error

Tags: c#, jquery, rest

I am trying to send data in post call of rest api. As data is quite big so i can not send it using query string. 
Below is My Ajax post call,

```
var urlstring = 'http://localhost/PersonAPI/api/Operations/TestMethod'
 $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: urlstring,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data:
                                {
                                    'employeedetails':JSON.stringify(exceljson)
                                },

                            success: function (data) {
                              //Some operation


                            }

                        });
```

My Rest api contains multiple post methods,
below is the api Controller,

```
public class OperationsController : ApiController
{

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [HttpRoute("api/Operations/UploadDetails")]
    public HttpResponseMessage UploadDetails(string EmployeeDetails)
    {
        //SomeCode
        return  Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.GenerateResponse());
    }


     [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
     [System.Web.Http.ActionName("TestMethod")]
     public HttpResponseMessage TestMethod(string EmployeeDetails)
     {
        //SomeCode
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.GenerateResponse());
     }
}
```

post sending the call it shows 404 error.
I tried to use form data but it returns string array. 
I am passing list of objects.This object has 6 properties. Input list is getting converted into json string while passing from jquery.
I am not getting how to pass the data

Comment: Can you show us the value of urlstring please? Also you controller declaration.

Comment: Is the confusion about what 404 means?

Comment: no I am finding why this 404 error is comeing up

Comment: OK, but you haven't provided the controller definition (only the method) and you haven't provided, what I'd think would be a key part, the URL that you're using.

Comment: i have updated the question @ John @ @CodeNotFound

Comment: Your URL should be `http://localhost/PersonAPI/api/Operations/TestMethod` instead of `localhost://PersonAPI/api/Operations/TestMethod`. Any why do you have `PersonAPI` ? DOes it mean virtual directory?

Comment: Doesn't `string EmployeeDetails` expect a query string parameter rather than a body? Don't you need `[FromBody]` and a model to deserialize to?

Comment: yes it's a virtual directory . i have hosted it in  iis. I am using the same url as suggested by you. it's typo error.

Comment: @John When I use FormBody then API get hit but EmployeeDetails parameter comes up with null value

Comment: I did say "and a model to deserialize to"

Comment: @John : I didn't get you can you explain with code example

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, `EmployeeDetails` expects a query-string parameter. You should use `[FromBody]`:

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
 [System.Web.Http.ActionName("TestMethod")]
 public HttpResponseMessage TestMethod([FromBody]EmployeeDetails employeeDetails)
 {
    //SomeCode
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.GenerateResponse());
 }
```

and create a corresponding model:

```
public class EmployeeDetails
{
    // add your properties
}
```

and on the front-end your request object should look like this:

```
{
    type: "POST",
    url: urlstring,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(exceljson)
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not working.. Is there any possible routing issue?

Comment: Must be. It's working for me - it solved the 404 problem. If I POST to `http://server/api/Operations/TestMethod` it hits and provides data. I don't understand how it's not working now, when you previously said it hits?

Comment: Yes it hits but data is not getting passed to api method. API Method "TestMethod" get null value.Can you check it by taking my system remote. my email id is pingaledu@gmail.com. plz mail me your id so i will share you team viewer credentials

Comment: @Pavan Oh, I see your problem now. You were trying to pass a name for a body parameter which is impossible unless you're using multi-part.

Comment: I tried that too to remove name . So i changed in ajax data: exceljson. also tried JSON.stringify(exceljson). but did not worked

Comment: @Pavan I've tried to reproduce the problem but I can't. The only thing I can think is that maybe your model doesn't match the JSOn you're posting. It might be worth posting a new question, including your JSON, model definition, etc. (since this is actually a different problem at this stage).

Answer (score 0):

404 error indicate that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.I think you should first check your API first in POSTMAN.Its working or not.Can i see ur backend code So i can try to solve your problem

Comment: The OP konw that => _no I am finding why this 404 error is comeing up_

Comment: When i pass parameter using query string then it's works but as i have more data then query string fails due to its limitation on size

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved when I used HttpRoute

Below is the code,

```
[HttpRoute("api/operations/TestMethod")] 
public HttpResponseMessage TestMethod(string EmployeeDetails)
     {
        //SomeCode
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.GenerateResponse());
     }
```